# Index-Match with Multiple Criteria in Different Workbooks Using Variables

Tags: excel, vba, indexing, criteria, matching

I am trying to use variables obtain from one workbook called "Mapping File.xlsx" as criteria in an INDEX/MATCH search in a different workbook called "Extract.xlsx" (both are Sheet1). The most important thing is that I need to search Column A for PartNumber (string), Column B for GroupCounter (String), and Column C for OperationNumb (String) and return the value found in Column G for ReturnValue (String).

Setting up my variables:

```
Dim PartNumber, GroupCounter, OperationNumb, ReturnValue As String 'Inputs are strings that are actually pulled from first workbook
PartNumber = Workbooks("Mapping File.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 1)
GroupCounter = Workbooks("Mapping File.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 2)
OperationNumb = Workbooks("Mapping File.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(5, 1)
```

Trying to use my variables to search a different workbook using INDEX/MATCHING:

Attempt 1

```
str = "=INDEX(G:G, MATCH(1, (PartNumber=A:A)*(GroupCounter=B:B)*(OperationNumb=D:D),0))"
ReturnValue = Workbooks("Extract.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Evaluate(str)
```

Attempt 2

```
str = "=INDEX(G:G, MATCH(PartNumber & GroupCounter & OperationNumb, Workbooks("Extract.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A") & Workbooks("Extract.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B:B") & Workbooks("Extract.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C:C")),0))"
ReturnValue = Workbooks("Extract.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Evaluate(str)
```

Attempts 3 - 30

I have tried to declare the ranges and use the variable names for the ranges in the MATCH_array. I have messed with declaring workbooks and worksheets. I have tried using a SUMPRODUCT. I have tried changing my variable types multiple times. I have messed with quotation marks and splitting the string up. I have tried splitting the INDEX and MATCH functions up. I have spent about 6 hours now on the google search to see whats out there, tweaking my code, and retesting and so now I'm looking for how this can be done. I don't want to hardcode the workbook or worksheets in to the INDEX/MATCHING function if I can avoid it due to the amount of times I will be using this capability in my larger code. So I'm looking for a way to pull 3 criteria from one sheet in 3 different cells, store them as strings, and then use those three strings to search through a second workbook to find the row that it occurs on, and use that row to return the value in a different column as a string (all with using as much variable names as possible to avoid much hardcoding). Any suggestions/ideas?

Comment: One problem in your first two is that Evaluate is very literal, so it's including the word "PartNumber" for example, in the formula. (It looks like you've maybe tried to address that in 3 to 30).

Answer (score 0):

How about using the autofiler?
If there is always only one record matching (or none) the selected criteria, the requested cell in column G should be always in the same row (after filtering out all other rows). 
The code is not elegant, but perhaps it would give some ideas. It copies rows matching the criteria to the separate sheet and shows the contents of the first row that matches these criteria.

```
Sub Makro2()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error Resume Next
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Results").Delete
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add.Name = "Results"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Sheets("Arkusz1").Select
    Cells.Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Selection.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="a" ` use PartNumber inestead of "a"
    Selection.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="b" `use GroupCounter instead of "b"
    Selection.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="c" ` use OperationNum instead of "c"
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    Sheets("Results").Paste
    Var = Sheets("Arkusz1").Range("G4")
    MsgBox Var
    Sheets("Arkusz1").Activate
    Cells.Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
End Sub
```

Another option is to use the function CONCATENATE to join these 3 criteria and make one string of them and then use VLOOKUP function. In an additional columny put this: =CONCATENATE(cell with PartNumber, cell with GroupCounter, cell with OpetationNum) and then use Vlookup like this =VLOOKUP(cell with cruteria1& cell with criteria2& cell with criteria3;search area;column G relative address number; 0)

```
    B   C   D   E   F   G   H
3   a   e   m   `=CONCATENATE(A1;B1;C1)         1
4   a   f   n   afn         2
5   b   g   o   bgo         3
6   b   h   p   bhp         4
7   c   i   q   ciq         5
8   c   j   r   cjr         6
9   d   k   s   dks         7
10  d   l   t   dlt         8
11                          
12                          
13  c   j   r   `=VLOOKUP(A11&B11&C11;$D$1:$G$8;4;0)
```